# ServiceProxy for current Service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to figure out how to generate a `ServiceProxy` that points to the service that I'm currently executing within. I have a need to convey information about it, so that another service can call back into this specific instance: since it's stateful.

`ServiceProxy` seems to do resolution by partition keys. However, I don't see how I can obtain a partition key for the currently executing service. I can obtain the partition Guid. But, ServiceProxy cannot be used with that.

Example use case: I have a `StatefulService` which invokes an external HTTP API. It posts a message to this API, which results in the API calling back into my infrastructure after some period. The HTTP endpoint that I have built needs to resolve the original `StatefulService` in order to route the response back to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the key range for the partition and send the low key value to the external HTTP API. When that external API needs to resolve the partition for the call back, it can use the low key value as the partition key, which guarantees it will fall in the right partition range:

```
Int64RangePartitionInformation partitionInfo = this.ServicePartition.PartitionInfo as Int64RangePartitionInformation;
long lowKey = partitionInfo.LowKey;
```